# Aligning horizontal divs into vertically

Tags: html, css

I have three horizontal `div`s in desktop screen, in mobile screen I want to make it aligned vertical taking the whole screen width. What CSS should i add to make it happen? Here is my code. thank you in advance.

```css
#demo1 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

#div1 {
  float: left;
  background: green;
  width: 25%;
}

#div2 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
}

#div3 {
  float: right;
  width: 25%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo1">
  <div id="div1">1</div>
  <div id="div2">2</div>
  <div id="div3">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display:flex` and `@media` queries

```css
#demo1 {
  width: 100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

#div1 {
  background: green;
  width: 25%;
}

#div2 {
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
}

#div3 {
  width: 25%;
  background: blue;
}

@media (max-width:992px) {
    #demo1 {
        flex-direction:column;
    }

    #div1, #div2, #div3 {
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="demo1">
  <div id="div1">1</div>
  <div id="div2">2</div>
  <div id="div3">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use display 'flex' @media query for mobile

```css
#demo1 {
  width: 100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

#demo1 > div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
}
    
#div1 {
  background: green;
  width: 25%;
}
    
#div2 {
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
}
    
#div3 {
  width: 25%;
  background: blue;
}

/*Mobie Screen*/
@media (max-width:800px) {
    #demo1 {
        flex-direction:column;
    }

    #demo1 > div {
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="demo1">
    <div id="div1">1</div>
    <div id="div2">2</div>
    <div id="div3">3</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using media queries, for example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
   demo1 {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     width: 100%;
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.